# I cant figure out how to create units, playable characters with basic stats, in a modular way in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I want to preface this with the fact that I am new to java and might be simply missing some basic understanding that could cover all of this so I deeply appreciate your understanding and help.

I'm looking to somehow create a program with java that allows for the creation of a playable character that will face a variety of npcs and eventually work with a party of playable characters and be modified by items from an inventory. This is the really important part, eventually I want build a game that could have any number of playable characters and any number of npcs all equipped with any number of inventory items so I must have a solution for generating characters, npcs, and inventory items that is modular.

Here is what I am trying to specifically work out, I want to create characters with at least the following attributes:

Unit Name, Unit Health, Unit Moves (action points), Unit Base Damage

Beyond this I want my units and npcs to be able to be modified by inventory. Basically say if one of my characters is holding a weapon I want that units base damage to be modified. You could imagine the same types of changes for armor, special items, and so on. This all seems straight forward but I cant figure out how to reconcile all of these properties together.

for example, this seems straight forward

```
//ex 1-1)

// from L to R: name, health, moves, damage
Ranger rangerObj0 = new Ranger("Ranger", 100, 4, 10);

// from L to R: name, description, damage modifying amount
Weapon weaponObj0 = new Weapon("Weapon Name", "Weapon description", 10);
```

but, how would I "relate" an item with this ranger? How do I semi-permanently, the item could be equipped or unequipped, modify the rangers stats with the value of gear? It seems like I would want to put all of these things in some kind of array so they could all be related and modified by their respective array locations like so:

Ranger array

```
//ex 1-2)

[0] rangerObj0
[1] rangerAttack1
[2] rangerAttack2
[3] weapon
[4] armor 
[5] special item
```

The problem I run into is that I am now dealing with different objects, types of variables, and calling methods that will have to reconcile the total stats a unit might have based on its base stats and innovatory in order to preform an attack for example.

This has been a long question but ultimately i am looking for a solution that would allow me to combine objects together like in ex 1-2 in a way that I could preform a method call like follows

```
//ex 1-3)

/*I would create code for the body of this method based on how I was able 
to relate all of a unit or npcs stats together*/

public attack1(unit attacking, unit getting attacked) {
    take attacking unit's base damage + damage from all equipped items + 
base damage from this attack and -= the unit's health that is getting 
attacked with regard to any armor or defensive stats the attacked unit 
might have;
}
```

this showcases the ultimate problem I have. I must find a way to create a method that takes in all off the parameters that my collection of objects and methods from ex 1-1 might have and use them against the collection of objects that comprises whatever unit I am attacking.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I would achieve this kind of relational programming like shown in ex 1-2?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is manifold, but I try to answer it as concise as possible.
I would suggest to introduce an interface that all Objects implement which gives you the stats, like

```
interface HasStats {

    int getForce();

    int getArmor();

    // ... REST
}
```

Then, your Ranger Class should inherit that.

```
public class Ranger implements HasStats {

    // Implementation here

}
```

All other Weaposn, Actions and so on also.

Furthermore, your Ranger gets all possible Slots as Fields like that

```
public class Ranger implements HasStats {

    Weapon currentWeapon;
    Action primaryAction;

    // Implementation here

    public void setWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
        this.currentWeapon = weapon;    
    }

    // more getters here

}
```

Finally, you can implement the `getStats()` mehtods in the ranger based on its equippment, like

```
public class Ranger implements HasStats {

    // Implementation here

    @Override
    public int getArmor() {
        return baseArmor + weapon.getArmor() * 2; // Just a dummy example
    }

    // Implementation here

}
```

I hope you can see the pattern and get the idea?

---

Edit:
If the interaction between the equipment and the stats is more complex you could use the visitor pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).
This would allow you to pass some stats to the equipment and let it do a calculation and return that back. But, this becomes easily pretty complicated so I'm not going into detail here.